# How do you remove a Mercurial repository

Tags: linux, mercurial

I accidently put a Mercurial repository in the wrong place. How do I remove it? This is in Linux.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Recursively remove the `.hg` directory? You can also just move it; they are portable, and the setup files inside of `.hg` contain no absolute paths that would break if placed elsewhere on the system.

From the comments: `rm -r .hg`

Comment: Fair enough, that's what I was going to do, I just assumed there was a 'proper' way to do it. Thanks for you help :)

Comment: Alas, no, there is no official Mercurial command, at least not one that I know about. They seem to prefer instead that people know a little about `.hg` instead of using a command line that hides that detail; for example, setting a default push location still requires (so far as I know?) that you manually edit `.hg/hgrc`.

Comment: Jonathan: Removing it is quite proper. We try to keep simple things simple in Mercurial: `hg init` creates `.hg` for you, and `rm -r .hg` will undo that.

Comment: Brandon: yes, you edit `.hg/hgrc` manually. There has been some talk about making a command that would open up the right file in your editor, but full-blown editing via the command line has been left out since using an editor ought to be easier for a programmer.

Comment: About editing configuration files: When people say that they prefer a command over editing the config file manually, Matt (the Mercurial project leader) often replies that this is like a doctor that cannot stand the sight of blood. Editing a configuration file in an editor of your choice should *not* be considered hard by programmers :-)

Comment: I'm using TortoiseHg on Windows 7 64-bit and it wouldn't allow me to delete the .hg directory the first time I tried. I looked around a bit, found this, and then tried deleting the contents of the directory first, then refreshing the icons, then deleting the directory and that seemed to work.